# How to control direct url access?

Tags: spring, url, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, struts2

How to control direct url access in jsf 2.0, struts 2 and spring 3 ? I mean not login user  type url and display always home or login page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use a project like **spring-security** to integrate with your application, or write your own **servlet-filter**

The stackoverflow [servlet-filter](/questions/tagged/servlet-filter) tag has a good overview of servlet filters. For most servlet compatible web frameworks you can integrate a filter to intercept requests and redirect invalid or unauthorized requests to where they belong.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander. That looks much better.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Apache Shiro filter for control direct access for a certain url.

Look at the Apache Shiro configuration ini file where are the control of url access shown.

```
[main]
logout = org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.LogoutFilter
roles  = org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authz.RolesAuthorizationFilter
authc.loginUrl=/faces/login.xhtml
authc.successUrl=/faces/index.xhtml
roles.unauthorizedUrl = /faces/unauthorized.xhtml
logout.redirectUrl = /faces/login.xhtml?status=loggedOut
jdbcRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = true
jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = SELECT PASSWORD FROM USERS WHERE USERS.USERNAME = ?
jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = SELECT ROLE_NAME FROM ROLES, USER_ROLE, USERS WHERE  ROLES.ROLE_ID = USER_ROLE.ROLE_ID AND USERS.USR_ID = USER_ROLE.USR_ID AND USERS.USERNAME = ?
jdbcRealm.permissionsQuery = SELECT PERMISSIONS.PERM_NAME FROM ROLES, PERMISSIONS_ROLE, PERMISSIONS WHERE  ROLES.ROLE_ID = PERMISSIONS_ROLE.ROLE_ID AND PERMISSIONS.PERM_ID = PERMISSIONS_ROLE.PERM_ID AND ROLES.ROLE_NAME = ?
ds = com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource 
ds.user = maqraa
ds.password = maqraa
ds.databaseName = maqraa
ds.serverName = localhost
ds.portNumber = 3306
jdbcRealm.dataSource = $ds
securityManager.realms = $jdbcRealm

[urls]
/faces/login.xhtml = authc
/faces/admin/** = authc, roles[admin]
/faces/teacher/** = authc, roles[teacher]
/faces/reports/** = authc, roles[admin]
/faces/officer/** = authc, roles[officer]
/faces/manager/** = authc, roles[manager]
/faces/roles/** = authc, roles[admin]
```

Looking at the previous url(s) you will find out that any access for /faces/login.xhtml must be done by authenticated user in addition to access some of url(s) you must be a playing for a specific role(s).

Review Shiro tag on stackoverflow or see the Apache Shiro site.

I hope that help you.
Thanks.